# Pass multiple args to a method with varargs of Object type

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameter-passing

In Java, I am trying to use a method from a library which accepts varargs of Object type:

```
static Result process(Object head, Object... tail)
```

In my code, the number of arguments is known at run time, so I tried to use an array to collect all arguments and pass them to `process(..)`:

```
T[] items = ...;
Result r = process(items);
```

However, as Array itself is an Object, the call does not unwrap array items and the whole array is considered as a single argument.

Any idea how multiple arguments can be boxed and passed to a method with varargs of Object type?

Comment: in java this is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a non-variadic parameter `head`.

This means that you require **at least** `head` to be passed to the method, with optional variadic arguments after.

Therefore, you should call:

```
Object[] allArgs = new Object[]{object1, object2, object3};
Object[] varags = Arrays.copyOfRange(allArgs, 1, allArgs.length);
process(allArgs[0], varags)
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the non-var "head" part. It works.